# randomly disperse numbers in array

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to randomly disperse different numbers in MATLAB array:

I have two 3's, four 2's and I want to randomly populate ones vector (size 10,1).

End result look something like this:

```
A = [1;3;1;2;3;2;2;1;1;2;1;1]
```

Then I want to fix the values in `A` but add more random elements but I can only replace with higher numbers:

For example, to the matrix above I will randomly add two more 2's and two more 3's giving something like this

> A= [**3**;3;**2**;2;3;2;2;**2**;1;2;1;**3**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First part**

You can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html) for that:

```
A = ones(1,12); %// original values
v = [3 3 2 2 2 2]; %// values to "disperse" in A

ind_replace = randsample(1:numel(A), numel(v)); %// index of entries to be replaced
A(ind_replace) = v;
```

If you don't have `randsample` (which is part of the Statistics Toolbox), use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) and select the first few elements:

```
ind_replace = randperm(numel(A));
ind_replace = ind_replace(1:numel(v));
A(ind) = v;
```

---

**Second part**

To only replace entries which equal 1:

```
v = [2 2 3 3]; %// values to "disperse" among the 1 values in A
ind_ones = find(A==1); %// index of entries which equal one
ind_replace = randsample(1:numel(ind_ones), numel(v)); %// index within the above
%// Or: ind_replace = randperm(numel(ind_ones));
%//     ind_replace = ind_replace(1:numel(v));
A(ind_ones(ind_replace)) = v;
```

Note this generalizes the first part, that is, it can also be used when all entries of `A` equal 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
M = [3;3;2;2;2;2];
M(end+1:end+4) = 1;

M=M(randperm(10))
```

The second half of your question needs a lot of clarification.

Comment: dan- thank you for quick comment.  I have clarified second half in original post.